# What is the meaning of "my face into their pussies with their crucifixes"?

Tags: meaning

In Drama film/Biography film *The People vs. Larry Flynt (1996)*, I know Althea really don't mean pussies because nuns
won't do such type of things.

> Althea: I had an epiphany once, Larry.
>
> Larry: What was that?
>
> Althea: When my daddy shot my entire family in the head, and I was the
>   only one to identify the bodies. I got sent to an orphanage full of
>   good, Christian nuns, who shoved **my face into their pussies with their
>   crucifixes** on for eight goddamn years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without more context.  Here "pussy" is a vulgar term for "vagina", but otherwise there are a couple possible interpretations:

1. The nuns used some kind of religious coercion to force Althea to give them oral sex.
2. A metaphorical interpretation of the above, that the nuns used religion to coerce a kind of maternal authority over Althea.

Either way, Althea does not have fond memories of that experience.  Again, I'd probably need more of the dialogue to understand how this relates to her *epiphany*.